# AWS S3 with Cloudfront CDN for different files according to behavior query string

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Currently I am serving some html pages on s3 with cloudfront. However, now I would like to serve a different index.html according to what I received in the parameter. For example: https://www.example.com?amp should serve an index.html different from the one already configured by default with https://www.example.com

Comment: That's not a CDN's job. You should configure your web server to do this.

Comment: yeah as jellycsc said its not cloudfront job, you can also use cloudfront function or Lambda@Edge to look at the requests parameter and change the  behaviour. is there a reason you are looking achieve it via query string instead of path pattern.  For example you can have amp-page path in url https://www.example.com/amp-page and that way you can use cloudfront to serve different index.html if its amp-page . In this case you can still cache the page and no need to whitelist querystring for caching behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using CloudFront Functions. Here is an example function you can use as a reference: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/tree/main/url-rewrite-single-page-apps

Additional consideration: You should also create a cache policy that generates a different cache key based on the presence of that query string parameter, so that the presence of the query string returns different content from cache than when the query string is not present.